# Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'android.content.Intent', required: 'android.content.Intent

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't solve this 'intent'problem!
When notification received my phone stop working with a message "System UI Stoped"
I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1

FirebaseMessagingService File>
 Here I'm getting an error for "PendingIntend.FLAG_ONE_SHOT" line. The "intent" has and red underlind and asking for an arry!

```
package firebase.com.firebasecloudmessaging;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("LiveCricket");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());



}
}
```

Manifest File>
Please check this file also,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="firebase.com.firebasecloudmessaging">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action         android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

FirebaseInstanceId File>
This file is not showing any error!

```
package firebase.com.firebasecloudmessaging;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends     FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token)

{

}

}
```

Build.gradle(Project)>
Please check the gradle file!

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(App level)>
Please check the gradle file!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "firebase.com.firebasecloudmessaging"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-    layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Getting error on line no.32 for FirebaseMessagingService File.

Comment: Could you post the crash logs?